# Property does not exist when using union type in typescript

Tags: typescript, union-types

Suppose that I have two interfaces:

```
interface Box {
    x: number
    y: number
}
```

and

```
interface ColouredBox {
    x: number
    y: number
    colour: string
}
```

*Assume for the purpose of this question, that I cannot change the interfaces.*

Now when constructing objects, I have code like this:

```
let a: Box|ColouredBox = {x: 1, y: 2}
if( something ){
    a.colour = "Blue"  // Compilation Error
}
```

I get this error on `a.colour = "Blue"`:

```
Error:(24, 26) TS2339: Property 'colour' does not exist on type 'Box'.
```

Why?  Is this a limitation of the TS compiler?  Other than completely reconstructing the object, is there a different workflow that I could use?

Comment: What's your original intention? The code at the moment makes very little sense from types perspective: if it should have a `colour` property - it should be a part of the type. If not - you should not set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using a Partial**

Instead of using a union type, you can try using a [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt)

```js
let a: Partial<ColouredBox> = {x: 1, y: 2}
```

The partial will set all the properties of the `ColoredBox` as optional.

Live example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeAoZQ5TALmRAFcBbAI2gKIE8zLb6BfPPUSWRFAMLoANugpQIAEwzZ8RYi2p0oDQs3JL68hCLFQyAZzBRQAczyc8wiGGRwyABThQwwOMIA8Q0eKkyAfMgAvLgKyACMADTI6gBMyOwA3FxwAHQ6PlDByABEqMIUEDnJOiAGIhCpoqYAFGkZegCUyUA).

**Update**:

**Eliminate an Interface**

If you only want the color part of the interface to be optional, you can eliminate one of the interfaces.

```js
interface Box {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  color?: string;
}
```

Then to determine if you're dealing with a colored box:

```
if (box.color) { ... }
```

**Type Assertion**

If you stick to using both interfaces, you can specifically treat `a` as a `ColouredBox` using the `as` keyword (a.k.a. a Type Assertion).

```js
let a: Box | ColouredBox = { x: 1, y: 2 };
(a as ColouredBox).colour = "Blue";
```

Comment: It changes semantics significantly: now you can do `a.x = undefined;`

Comment: Choosing this as the best answer because of the `type assertion` section.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`in` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator):

```
if ("colour" in a) {
    a.colour = "Blue"  // works
}
```

This will narrow to the union part `ColouredBox` based on the existence of property `colour`. In general, you can only select all common properties `x`/`y` of `Box | ColouredBox`, when not narrowed before.

[Live code sample here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeAoZQ5TALmRAFcBbAI2gKIE8zLb6BfPPUSWRFAMLoANugpQIAEwzZ8RYi2p0oDQs3JL68hCLFQyAZzBRQAczyc8AeivIwjAA4o4Bg9DDB0IZACsKRu3RkKjgAaxQAFQBlcnQwQKCDEKh4gHdgMAALZB1wKBFkGFFU5FA7TOADZAMnBGAYYARkCEw4KgdhCDxO+LgyGWQAH2QhUXEpAYBeXAVkAEYAGmR1ACZkdmQXNCwhkd1x6R3uGGQACgAiHTGoc9LvOABKXFVNgDorvWRp89RhCghbsgbHt2sBhHAPF5kABRKD5FTsIA)

Comment: The `if(something)` is a check to see if should be set, not if it has been set.